# Extract all matches from given string

Tags: javascript, regex, split, match, trim

I have string:

> =?windows-1256?B?IObH4cPM5dLJIA==?= =?windows-1256?B?x+HYyO3JIC4uLg==?= =?windows-1256?B?LiDH4djj5s3Hyg==?= =?windows-1256?B?Rlc6IOTP5skgKA==?=

I need to extract all matches between `?B?` and `==?=`.

As a result I need:

> IObH4cPM5dLJIA
>
> x+HYyO3JIC4uLg
>
> LiDH4djj5s3Hyg
>
> Rlc6IOTP5skgKA

P.S. This string is taken from textarea and after function executed, script should replace current textarea value with result. I've tried everything,

```
var result = str.substring(str.indexOf('?B?')+3,str.indexOf('==?='));
```

Works almost the way I need, but it only finds first match. And this doesn't work:

```
function Doit(){
    var str = $('#test').text();
    var pattern = /(?B?)([\s\S]*?)(==?=)/g;
    var result = str.match(pattern);

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $('#test').html(result);
    };
}
```

Comment: use pattern : /(\?B\?)(.*?)(==\?=)/g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` has a special meaning in regex which matches preceding character 0 or 1 time..

So, `?` should be escaped with `\?`

---

So the regex should be

```
(?:\?B\?)(.*?)(?:==\?=)
```

`[\s\S]` has no effect and is similar to `.`

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful and almost does what I need. Now it's generates: `?B?IObH4cPM5dLJIA==?=?B?x+HYyO3JIC4uLg==?=?B?LiDH4djj5s3Hyg==?=?B?Rlc6IOTP5skgKA==?=` 

How do I remove ?B? and ==?= from the result and how to add a linebreak between results?

Comment: @Artjom you need to access group 1's value..[here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex) how it is done

Comment: Oh, I've done it. Maybe it's not an elegant way, however it works :)

    function Doit(){var str = $('#test').text();var pattern = /(\?B\?)(.*?)(==\?=)/g;var result str.match(pattern); $('#test').html(result); var cont = $('#test').text(); var final = cont.replace(/(\?B\?)/g,''); var final2 = final.replace(/(==\?=)/g,'<br/>'); $('#test').html(final2);}

Answer (score 0):

The metacharacter `?` needs escaping, i.e. `\?` so it is treated as a literal `?`.

`[\s\S]` is important as it matches all characters *including* newlines.

```
var m,
    pattern = /\?B\?([\s\S]*?)==\?=/g;

while ( m = pattern.exec( str ) ) {
    console.log( m[1] );
}

// IObH4cPM5dLJIA
// x+HYyO3JIC4uLg
// LiDH4djj5s3Hyg
// Rlc6IOTP5skgKA
```

Or a longer but perhaps clearer way of writing the above loop:

```
m = pattern.exec( str );

while ( m != null ) {
    console.log( m[1] );
    m = pattern.exec( str );
}
```

The String `match` method does not return capture groups when the global flag is used, but only the full match itself.

Instead, the capture group matches of a global match can be collected from multiple calls to the RegExp `exec` method. Index `0` of a match is the full match, and the further indices correspond to each capture group match. See [MDN exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).